# How to increase the year of widget DateField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form follow as:

```
class UserProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    birthday = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={"class": "datepicker input-medium"}, format=('%m/%d/%Y')),
        error_messages={'required': 'Birthday is required.'})
```

This date picker only displays the year from 1900 to 2012. So, user can not choose a date in 2013 or the future year. Please see the picture below.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I have to ask, how you can have a birth date in the future?

Comment: Hi Burhan, it's just an example. However, thank you for your question :D

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a jQueryUI issue. Have you checked their docs?

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

Should give you a good datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the widget to "SelectDateWidget" and specify the date range (untested here):

```
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
class UserProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    birthday = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1900, 2100),
            error_messages={'required': 'Birthday is required.'})
```